# Creating a list with input from 2 EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am making a app where part of it is a list of the books you have read, with the title and the author in each entry.  I have 2 EditText boxes and 1 button.  I want to take the title and the author from the boxes when I tap the button and put them in a list entry together.  I have the part where it takes the data from the boxes and assigns them each to a variable already, I am just having troubles with the list.  Heres the code I have so far:

```
    package com.lijap.apps.BookTracker;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class BooksRead extends ListActivity {

Button addbook;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.booksread);
       addbook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_addbook);
       addbook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //called when you press the button
            String bookName =((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_title)).getText().toString();
            String bookAuthor =((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_author)).getText().toString();
            // do the rest of the job

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any list related code here, what have you done so far?

Comment: I have created a listview in a xml file that the setContentView is using, I couldn't figure out how to combine lists and arrayadapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the listview is a fundamental element that you might use very often, so id strongly suggest that you read some good articles on it. There are different ways of implementing it depending on how you are going to use it. For example you can have list entries each with a custom layout, you can optimize your listview so that elements are recycled when they are not in the view so on and so forth....
Try out this tutorial on listview. It explains most of the elements in good detail.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
You can find more extensive tutorials on listview quite easily on the net.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the article, it looks like it will really help.